# An absolute maximum is always be the largest?

Tags: calculus

It has been written in many text books "An absolute maximum (or minimum) is the largest (or smallest) value that the function will ever take on the domain that we are working on."..........(*)

Is it really correct? Then what about $\sec(x)$ in its whole domain? It is easily seen from the graph of $\sec(x)$, it has countably infinite number of minimum values, all are +1 and countably infinite number of maximum values, all are -1. In fact all of its minimum values are greater than all of its maximum values. So what is the largest value? +1 or -1.

If (*) statement is true, then largest value is -1
and least value is +1. Does it really sound logical, largest is negative and least is positive? 
And what about $x + \frac{1}{x}$ where for the same reason largest is -2 and least is +2?

Comment: Some functions don't have a maximum. Your statement is the definition of "absolute maximum" (more commonly called _global_ maximum).

Comment: You are confusing between local maximum and absolute maximum. $\sec x$ has points of local maximum where the value attained is $+1$. That doesn't make it a global (absolute maximum). In fact a function may not even have the derivative zero at a point of absolute maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The secant function has no global maximum or minimum. Like all real functions, it has a [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) (which is $+\infty$ for secant), and an infimum (which is $-\infty$ for secant).

It has many *local* maxima and minima, which is what the OP is referring to, but this is immaterial.  The definition as written is correct; what is incorrect is concluding that 1 and -1 are absolute maxima or minima.